# How to avoid proposing a page if you go back

Tags: inno-setup

I made a script (my first) in InnoSetup that works very well except in a particular condition. Let me explain:

Here is my **new** script :

```
[Types]
Name: "Base"; Description: "Local Database"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: "baselocal"; Description: "Standard Installation : install program and local database"; Types: Base; Flags: exclusive
Name: "baseserver"; Description: "Installation with server database : install program and choose directory for database"; Types: Base; Flags: exclusive

...

[code]
var
  BasePage: TInputDirWizardPage;
  BasePageID: Integer;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CurPageID = wpSelectComponents then begin
    if (IsComponentSelected('baseserver')) then
                begin

                  Result := (MsgBox('La base ne sera pas installée localement. Vous devrez spécifiez un chemin. ' +
                  'Voulez-vous continuer ?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES);
                  // create a directory input page
                  BasePage := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectComponents, 'Choix de la base', 'Caneco BT peut gérer une base sur un serveur ou en local. Veuillez indiquez le chemin de la base qui vous intéresse.', 'Dossier Base de Données', False, '');
                  // add directory input page items
                  BasePage.Add('Sélectionnez un chemin :');
                  // assign default directories for the items from the previously stored data; if
                  // there are no data stored from the previous installation, use default folders
                  // of your choice
                  BasePage.Values[0] := GetPreviousData('Directory1', ExpandConstant('{pf}\program\'));
                  BasePageID := BasePage.ID;
                  exit;
                end;     
  end;
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  // initialize result to not skip any page (not necessary, but safer)
  Result := False;
  // if the page that is asked to be skipped is your custom page, then...
  if PageID = BasePageID then
    // if the component is not selected, skip the page
    Result := not IsComponentSelected('baseserver');
end;
```

(If you see any errors, please tell me, thank you)

Now with the "ShouldSkipPage" function, ti's working but if i select "baseserver" two times (one times, come back and reselect one times... I know this is twisted but i test all possibility), it propose the "BasePage" two times in a row...

Is there a solution to avoid this ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer for initial question

```
[Types]
Name: "Base"; Description: "Local Database"; Flags: iscustom

[Components]
Name: "baselocal"; Description: "Standard Installation : install program and local database"; Types: Base; Flags: exclusive
Name: "baseserver"; Description: "Installation with server database : install program and choose directory for database"; Types: Base; Flags: exclusive

...

[code]
var
  BasePage: TInputDirWizardPage;
  BasePageID: Integer;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CurPageID = wpSelectComponents then begin
    if (IsComponentSelected('baseserver')) then
                begin

                  Result := (MsgBox('La base ne sera pas installée localement. Vous devrez spécifiez un chemin. ' +
                  'Voulez-vous continuer ?', mbConfirmation, MB_YESNO) = IDYES);
                  // create a directory input page
                  BasePage := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectComponents, 'Choix de la base', 'Caneco BT peut gérer une base sur un serveur ou en local. Veuillez indiquez le chemin de la base qui vous intéresse.', 'Dossier Base de Données', False, '');
                  // add directory input page items
                  BasePage.Add('Sélectionnez un chemin :');
                  // assign default directories for the items from the previously stored data; if
                  // there are no data stored from the previous installation, use default folders
                  // of your choice
                  BasePage.Values[0] := GetPreviousData('Directory1', ExpandConstant('{pf}\program\'));
                  BasePageID := BasePage.ID;
                  exit;
                end;     
  end;
end;

function ShouldSkipPage(PageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  // initialize result to not skip any page (not necessary, but safer)
  Result := False;
  // if the page that is asked to be skipped is your custom page, then...
  if PageID = BasePageID then
    // if the component is not selected, skip the page
    Result := not IsComponentSelected('baseserver');
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried adding `Boolean` as an additional condition?

```
[Code]
var
  DirPage: TInputDirWizardPage;
  DirPageID: Integer;
  BasePageCreated: Boolean;

function NextButtonClick(CurPageID: Integer): Boolean;
begin
  Result := True;
  if CurPageID = wpSelectComponents then begin
    if (IsComponentSelected('baseserver')) and (not BasePageCreated) then
                begin
                  BasePageCreated := True;
                  // create a directory input page
                  DirPage := CreateInputDirPage(wpSelectComponents, 'Choix de la base', 'Caneco BT peut gérer une base sur un serveur ou en local. Veuillez indiquez le chemin de la base qui vous intéresse.', 'Dossier Base de Données', False, '');
                  // add directory input page items
                  DirPage.Add('Sélectionnez un chemin :');
                  // assign default directories for the items from the previously stored data; if
                  // there are no data stored from the previous installation, use default folders
                  // of your choice
                  DirPage.Values[0] := GetPreviousData('Directory1', ExpandConstant('{pf}\program\'));
                  DirPageID := DirPage.ID;
                  exit;
                end;

    if (IsComponentSelected('baselocal')) or (BasePageCreated) then
       exit;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: I would forget what `baseserverbool` variable does soon. Variable like e.g. `BasePageCreated` would better describe its purpose.

Comment: In this context it would be actually `DirPageCreated`. But anyway, you don't need to use a variable for that. Simply ask `if not Assigned(DirPage) then...`. When you are creating that page, you are assigning it to that variable, so the next time the `DirPage` variable will have `Assigned` an object instance.

Comment: Hmm, i try your solution (@Roben and "if not Assigned" from @TLama) but the problem persist. If i change advice, selecting "baseserver" first, come back to the component page and selecting "baselocal", it still propose the "dirpage"... (or maybe i wrote the code wrong)

Comment: Maybe you should `Destroy` page when going back or add `ShouldSkipPage` for that situation?

Comment: Yes that's what i do, i edit my script and now i have another problem. Looks above :)